# Batch open file in it folder

Tags: batch-file

i want to open a file using **batch** file but it require to done in it folder

Example :
Source File : folder1\file.exe
Batch File : batch.bat

i tried :

```
Start folder1\Set-up.exe
```

but it don't work because in that folder there are files missing and they are only available at folder1

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use

```
@ECHO OFF
start /d "path" file.exe
pause
```

You can use this format to open more than one .exe setup at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)

Edit **batch.bat**

```
@echo off
cd resources
start Set-up.exe
```

Thanks